# Error parsing JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing

I have a problem parsing my JSON result with specific term.

This my JSON sample result : http://bit.ly/1FbZbde

If in "curriculum" I have "__class": "chapter", I'm looking for a result of:

```
<h2>Title from chapter</h2>
```

and if I have "__class": "lecture", I'm looking for a result of:

```
<li>Title from lecture</li>
```

My code:

```
<?php foreach($json['curriculum'] as $item) { ?>
<li><i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i> <?php echo $item['title']; ?></li>
<?php } ?>
```

My results include all titles from chapters and lectures.

Comment: So if the "__class" is a lecture you want the title in a <li> , and if "__class" is a chapter, you want it in a <h2> ?

Comment: yes.. that i want..  let me know if you know how to do that..

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question right.
So if the `__class` is lecture you want the title in a `<li>` and if the `_class` is a chapter, you want the title in a `<h2>`.

```
<?php foreach($json['curriculum'] as $item): ?>
    <?php if ($item['__class'] == 'chapter'): ?>
        <h2><i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i>
            <?php echo $item['title']?> 
        </h2>
    <?php elseif ($item['__class'] == 'lecture'): ?>
        <li><i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i> 
        <?php echo $item['title'] ?>
        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: that's why i like this community... thank's for your help sir.. will modify this one to get more result..

Comment: the li tag is only allowed in an ul or ol... and h2 is not (ul nor ol) - correct me if im wrong